# Change domain name (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, database, migration

I have civi crm 4.7.8 on wordpress 4.5.3 and I've changed my website domain name.
When I go to wp admin, i can see civicrm icon and go the taskboard, but I haven't civicrm menu.
I supposed there are some changes to do in database to set new domain name ?
Can you hep me ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Below are the simplified instructions taken from [Moving an Existing Installation to a New Server or Location](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Moving+an+Existing+Installation+to+a+New+Server+or+Location), but specific to answer your question.

1. Open the file wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.settings.php in any text editor and change the value for CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL with your new domain name
   For CiviCRM Version 4.7 open the file `wp-content/uploads/civicrm/civicrm.settings.php`
2. Login into WP and navigate to

http://[your domain name]/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/admin/setting/updateConfigBackend&reset=1

and clear cache and save the new base directory/path settings

3. Rebuild CiviCRM menu by navigating to

http://[your domain name]/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/menu/rebuild&reset=1

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer.

In wp-content/plugins/civicrm, I haven't the file civicrm.settings.php (maybe because I'm in 4.7.8 version ?)

I have civicrm.php but there is no URL in.

Comment: Was CiviCRM installed and working fine before the domain name change? If yes, then there should be civicrm.settings.php file in 'wp-content/plugins/civicrm' directory, as this file will be automatically created during installation.

Comment: For CiviCRM Version 4.7 open wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.settings.php  Answer edited for CiviCRM version 4.7, but seems I need peer review

Comment: Yes civicrm was working fine before the domain name change (no hosting changes).

Comment: @KevinCristiano Thanks for the edit. Laure - Can you please check the above mentioned directory for CiviCRM 4.7

Comment: Excellent - Laura: can you please mark Kevin's answer as the solution (hit the check mark) - to keep SE happy. Thanks!